# Fix OS X Application Loader Java Version

Tags: java, xcode, macos

Strangely my Application loader is using wrong version of Java and I want to change it to correct version. How I can do this?

**Wrong Version**

[image]

**Correct Version is**
[image]

[image]

Comment: This should help you... http://superuser.com/questions/650310/switching-between-java-7-and-8-in-os-x

Comment: @Jackie - Thanks. But issue is not switching between different versions of java but making sure **Application Loader** use the correct version of Java.

Comment: The loader java is at `./Applications/XCode ... bin/java`, which is the one you should be checking the version on. The native versions you have on MacBook-Pro are earlier than `1.7.0`, of which obviously isn't installed there.

Comment: @lll - Thanks. I had 1.8 previously and it was not working for it either. I believe I need 1.7 specifically, am I right?